# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when saving model

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got several ModelAdmin classes and I'd like to do the same action when save the model so I created mixin object for this purpose:

```
class SaveModelMixin(object):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.is_executed and 'is_executed' in obj.changed_data:
            obj.date_execution = datetime.date.today()
        super(self.__class__, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

And when I try to save object in admin, this method just runs itself again and again, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `super()` call is incorrect, try this:

```
super(SaveModelMixin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

See explanation here: [How to avoid infinite recursion with super()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235078/how-to-avoid-infinite-recursion-with-super)

Also see:

- [Django Model: How to use mixin class to override django model for function likes save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705158/django-model-how-to-use-mixin-class-to-override-django-model-for-function-likes)